# Multiple show() and hide() effects in jQuery UI 1.9 Tabs

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

Before jQueryUI 1.9, I was able to use the following to toggle both the opacity and height at the same time:

```
$('#site-tabs').tabs({
    fx: {opacity: 'toggle', height: 'toggle'},
});
```

Now that it was noted in the [upgrade guide](http://jqueryui.com/upgrade-guide/1.9/#deprecated-fx-option-use-show-and-hide-options) that `fx` is deprecated and to use the `show()` and `hide()` methods instead -- I can't figure out how to pass two effects to it. I've tried:

show: [{effect: "opacity"}, {effect: "slideToggle"}]

to no avail. Any pointers? Thanks as always!

Answer (score 1):

@Zach I know this is rather old, but I had the same issue and I just wanted to confirm that you were on to something.

You can indeed build your own effect:

```
$.fn.slideFadeToggle  = function(speed, easing, callback) {
    return this.animate({opacity: 'toggle', height: 'toggle'}, speed, easing, callback);
};
```

and use it like this `show: { effect: "slideFadeToggle", duration: 500 }`.

Answer (score 0):

It is explained pretty well i think in the [documentation](http://api.jqueryui.com/tabs/#option-show).

```
$( ".selector" ).tabs({ show: { effect: "slide", duration: 800 } })
```

However, i don't see how you could make that both slide AND fade given the new api.

Comment: I need multiple effects though, slide and fade

Comment: @Zach I don't think that is possible with the new api. It only allows for one effect to be passed in.

Comment: What the funk :) then I guess `The fx option has been deprecated in favor of new show and hide options. The show and hide options provide more customization over animations.` is pretty meaningless huh?

Comment: You could however create your own custom slideFade effect and use that.

Comment: Something like [this](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/jquery/combine-slide-and-fade-functions/)? And then pass it as `show: slideFadeToggle()` Any pointers would be a huge help

Comment: That's not a jQuery ui effect, that's a function. I haven't made any effects myself, but you can find code for the existing effects here: https://github.com/jquery/jquery-ui/tree/master/ui and possibly find a way to combine slide and fade into a single effect.

Comment: Almost there with:  `beforeActivate: function(event, ui) {
        var newPanel = $(ui.newPanel);
        var oldPanel = $(ui.oldPanel);
        oldPanel.animate({opacity: 'toggle', height: 'toggle'});
        newPanel.animate({opacity: 'toggle', height: 'toggle'});
    }`